# Why does part of my model shrink when rotating the bone it is weight painted to?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

So I'm a beginner in blender, and I was testing rigging in a model. I tried automatic weights but when I moved the arm a bunch of other parts of the body moved as well, so I erased all their weights and re-painted them myself with the gradient brush in their right place, but when I started testing the movement of the arm, I rotated the bone, but the arm was quite off. It rotated but not at the same rate as the bone, and the more it rotates the more it shrinks into oblivion. I raised the strength and it got a little better but still pretty bad. I erased all the other bones to see if they were causing the problem but they weren't.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think that you have painted too much on the upper arm bone. Try to assign that bone only to the upper arm.

Comment: thank you, i tried a few diferent things based in your segestion and i found something that worked